# pom.xml shows multiple annotations errors in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I can build the project from command line, but when I import it to Eclipse I get following error in pom.xml:

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
- Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: 
 org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources 
 (execution: default-testResources, phase: process-test-resources)
- Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: 
 org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources 
 (execution: default-resources, phase: process-resources)
```

Eclipse Maven Integration plugin is using Maven version `3.2.1`, and my system is also using the same version.

What could be the reason for this error? How to resolve it?

Comment: This looks pretty similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9142533/plugin-execution-not-covered-by-lifecycle-configuration-jbossas-7-ear-archetype

Comment: Change your eclipse configuration to use the JDK instead of the JRE.

Comment: See it here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21099229/460557

Comment: @mephi42   I tried doing changes mentioned in that answer but it is still giving the error.

Comment: @JorgeCampos Yes eclipse configuration is pointing to the JDK only not JRE

Comment: @Amruta What about the Maven configuration is it using the embedding maven from eclipse or the external maven version? Point it to the external maven if it is pointing to embedded.

Comment: http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_plugin_execution_not_covered

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting Error in POM.xml on KEPLER Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23952407/getting-error-in-pom-xml-on-kepler-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

1. You should install or update M2Eclipse i.e. Maven integration for
   eclipse
2. Restart eclipse
3. Delete project and add project again

This should resolve your error

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following things:

1. Right click on your project > Maven Clean Verify .
2. Ok, this seems odd but; check your pom.xml file encoding. Be sure it's UTF-8. Also, one time, I tried this and worked for me; I just saved the pom.xml file again in notepad++ . (nothing did special, just clearing some spaces for saving the file again) After this, eclipse didn't give an error about pom.xml file.